# Let $B$ be a nilpotent matrix, prove that $I-B$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B$ be a nilpotent matrix, prove that $I-B$ is invertible, and find the inverse of $I-B$.

Well I'm kinda lost here. I tried computing $(I-B)*(I-B)^{-1}$ and get to a point where are I have something like $B*B$ $(=0)$ and then somehow to show that it all equals $I$. Any help?

Comment: Do you know the power series of $\frac{1}{1-z}$ for $|z| <1$?

Comment: no i am just beginning :(

Comment: Ah, well for $|z|<1$ you have $ (1-z) \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k - \sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k =1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $B^n=0$, use the factorisation, valid in any ring with unit:
$$1-x^n=(1-x)(1+x+\dots+x^{n-1}).$$

This shows, more generally, that in any ring, if $x$  is nilpotent, $1-x$ or $1+x$ are invertible.

Comment: hey bernard thank you... i don't understand this formula, could you please explain it to me?

Comment: @donna For examples you have the following: $(1-x^2)=(1-x)(1+x)$.  $(1-x^3)=(1-x)(1+x+x^2)$.  $(1-x^{100})=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{99})$.  (You should be able to convince yourself why this is true without too much tedious checking).  Bernard reminds us that this is valid for *any ring* (things you can multiply and add that satisfy some "nice" properties) and in particular this works for matrices.  Here, we have that $I-B^2 = (I-B)(I+B)$, we have that $I-B^3=(I-B)(I+B+B^2)$, etc...  In particular, if $B^n=0$ we have $I = I-B^n = (I-B)(I+B+B^2+\dots+B^{n-1})$.  Now, remember def of invertible.

Comment: Well, you can develop it. If $x$ is a real or complex number, it's a high-school formula, which i the basic fact that leads to the formula for the sum of consecutiuve terms in a geometric progression. What is it you don't understand, exactly?

Comment: Ok so how does it help me to prove that $I-B$ is invertible? All I know is that $B*B = 0$. What gives me the right to start checking $I-B^{2}$?

Comment: It's  up to you to start where you want. If $B^2=0$, it doesn't cost much to write $I=I-B^2=(I-B)(I+B)$. Now a matrix is invertible if you can find another matrix such  that their product is $I$.

Comment: @Bernard , is it also ok to assume that $I+B$ is invertible? Because $I = (I-B^{2}) = -(B^{2}-I) = -(B+I)(B-I) = -(I+B)(B-I) = (I+B)(I-B) = I$ ?

Comment: Not to exactly `assume`, but to consider this also `proves` $I+B$ is invertible – that's what I added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative Proof

If $I-A$ is not invertible,.then there exists $x\neq 0$ such that $(I-A)x=0\implies Ax=x\implies A^kx=A^{k-1}Ax=A^{k-1}x=...=x$

Which contradicts the fact that that $A^m=0$